# what happens to the sample points on pruned leaves

Tags: classification, decision-trees

I think I understand what pruning is (in concept) in a decision tree. What is not so clear to me (in reading) is what happens to the pruned observations. What do you do with them? Are they just simply not used and forgotten?

What bothers me is the "hole" left behind by the pruned node. What if a future $Y$ needs to be predicted at that node? Do you go to the parent node and treat that parent node as an end node and predict $Y$ by the data at that parent node (even though some data at the parent node continue to be divided in sub-nodes, other than the pruned node)?

Comment: What do you mean by incidents here exactly?

Comment: I thought Incidents meant "observations" in ML terminology. Is that not true?

Comment: I personally never heard that term. Typically, I would use terms like inputs, data points, input features/variables, instances. And what you're trying to predict is generally referred to as the target, gold truth, label.

Answer (score 1):

Once you prune nodes, they get removed from the tree altogether, so you wouldn't be able to predict based on them.

Typically, hyperparaneter tuning is used to ensure that the right nodes are pruned. Obviously, there is always a trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Pruning doesn't operate on individual leaves, it happens to splits: you decide not to make a split at a node after all, and so all the observations that would go through that node in the original tree will stay at that node, which is now a leaf.

Comment: Are you sure about this? You are saying that the decision is on whether or not to split - that is to say, at a node, either all or none leaves are kept. This sounds a bit doubtful intuitively - an unnecessary rigidity. (?)

Comment: Quite confident.  The trees are built in that fashion, and (post-)pruning essentially undoes some of those splits.  Some more reading:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_cost_complexity_pruning.html (you could rerun that and add `plot_tree`, maybe),
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rpart/versions/4.1-15/topics/prune.rpart,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree_pruning